# delete svn folder (encode error),looks like unicode error

Tags: svn, urlencode, gb2312

My svn server is Visual SVNServer, two year's ago ,I commit a code to svn, the folder's name contains chinese, when I list folder by svn command,it shows

`?\197?\250?\193?\191?\199?\169?\195?\251/`

I can't enter this folder . so I want delete it.

I know,maybe it's GB2312 encode, but how can I delete it?

I had try two ways:
1.use svnserver's early version in winxp
2.use early version too, and set lang=zh_cn.GB2312 in linux

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete it with **TortoiseSVN Repo Browser**, 
or on a linux shell with UTF-8 Support(standard in alll common distributions).

Unfortunately the standard commandshell does not support UTF-8, therefore the international characters cannot be shown.

Setting the lang variable will only change the svn's messages to the specified language, it will not transform any data delivered by repository.

You can however try to set the codepage on windows, however I do not know what codepage you need.

Comment: thx peter。In TortoiseSVN, it can’t open this folder, and can't delete. It's not UTF-8 encode, It encoded by GB2312. I had try set the codepage ,but can't resoved it